# Excel VBA Only Allow Administrator to Modify Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some issues with VBA to allow only Administrators to modify an excel workbook. Can anyone help me with the code to make this happen? Thanks!

Comment: Part of the answer is to lock or unlock the workbook with a password when it opens, if the user is an member of the administrators group. I have done this, but only for a specific user (based on userid). I cannot think how to get windows identity information in VBA, but I am sure it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the username is fairly straightfoward:

```
 username = Environ("UserName")
```

It is also possible through API calls, which is detailed [here](http://blogs.officezealot.com/charles/archive/2004/12/10/3574.aspx)

You can then check that username against your list of administrators. If they are in the list, you can then unprotect the workbook.

```
 ThisWorkbook.Unprotect
```